# Fit an image depending on available width

Tags: html, css

I am creating a carousel and I am having trouble displaying the images depending of the width of the available width. My images are around 350 by 250 px and I am trying to stretch them to fill with the whole window

```css
<style>
 .mainLeftContent
 {
  width: 80%;
 }
 .slider 
 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%; /* Update to your slider width */
  height: auto; /* Update to your slider height */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

 .slider li {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
 }
</style>
```

```html
<div id ="mainLeftContent">
 <ul id="MainContentPlaceHolder_caruselUl" class="slider">
  <li><a href="Recipe.aspx?RecipeId=14013">
   <img class="caruselImageClass" src="../images/RecipeImages/635635997646632016.JPG" /></a>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see the imgs being styled in your code. Oh, and the snippet doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time.
I solved my problem using java script and setting the width of the .slider dynamically.